# Magic bouncing ball problem

Tags: algorithm, math

> Mary got a magic ball for her birthday. The ball, when thrown from
>   some height, bounces for the double of this height. Mary's thrown the
>   ball from her balcony which is `x` above the ground. Help her
>   calculate how many bounces are there needed for the ball to reach whe
>   height `w`.
>
> Input: One integer `z` (1 ≤ z ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>) as the number of test cases. For
>   every test, integers `x` and `w` (1 ≤ x ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>, 0 ≤ w ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>).
>
> Output: For every case one integer equal to the number of bounces
>   needed fot the ball to reach `w` should be printed.

OK, so, though it looks unspeakably easy, I can't find a more efficient way to solve it than a simple, dumb, brutal approach of a loop multiplying `x` by 2 till it's at least `w`. For a maximum test, it will get a horrific time, of course. Then, I thought of using previous cases which saves quite a bit time providing that we can get the closest yet smaller result from the previous cases in a short time (O(1)?) which, however, I can't (and don't know if it's possible..) implement. How should this be done?

Comment: Try a logarithm perhaps.

Comment: Have you heard of [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)? (But since the number of bounces will be at most 30 under the given restrictions, there is nothing really "horrific" about the naive algorithm).

Comment: Surely you just need to use logarithms. e: too sloooooooow

Comment: But how can logarithms help here? Firstly, the ball doubles it's bounce-height, not gets it to the next power and secondly - it's not said that it has to get the exact height - the closest above it may be the answer as well.

Comment: Double the previous number _is_ the next power (of 2).

Comment: @Hammerite, it took me some time to figure your that you didn't mean that _natural_ logarithms would be too sloooow :-)

Comment: Yes, but the w doesn't have to be 2. What then?

Comment: @Kerrek When I read that, I seriously thought you were making an XKCD reference ("Have you tried logarithms?")

Comment: @Jared: Can you post the link?!

Comment: @Kerrek [Have you tried logarithms?](http://www.xkcd.com/451/)

Comment: I wanted to mention, as this is -specifically- using multiples of two, you can use the properties of binary integers to your advantage. If you perform a left bitwise shift on x, it effectively multiplies x by 2. Unless the multiplication algorithm uses this property, this approach will be faster than multiplication.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thank you all very much! :)

Comment: Oh, one more thing! I did the logarithm thing but for x=1000000000 and w=999999999 I get the output "-0". Why is it negative? Should I use abs() for every output, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially trying to solve the problem

> 2<sup>i</sup> x = w

and then finding the smallest integer greater than i.  Solving, we get

> 2<sup>i</sup> = w / x
>
> i = log<sub>2</sub> (w / x)

So one approach would be to compute this value explicitly and then take the ceiling.  Of course, you'd have to watch out for numerical instability when doing this.  For example, if you are using `float`s to encode the values and then let w = 8,000,001 and x = 1,000,000, you will end up getting the wrong answer (3 instead of 4).  If you use `double`s to hold the value, you will also get the wrong answer when x = 1 and w = 536870912 (reporting 30 instead of 29, since 1 x 2<sup>29</sup> = 536870912, but due to inaccuracies in the double the answer is erroneously rounded up to 30).  It looks like we'll have to switch to a different approach.

Let's revisit your initial solution of just doubling the value of x until it exceeds w should be perfectly fine here.  The maximum number of times you can double x until it reaches w is given by log<sub>2</sub> (w/x), and since w/x is at most one billion, this iterates at most log<sub>2</sub> 10<sup>9</sup> times, which is about thirty times each.  Doing thirty iterations of a multiply by two is probably going to be extremely fast.  More generally, if the upper bound of w / x is U, then this will take at most O(log U) time to complete.  If you have k (x, w) pairs to check, this takes time O(k log U).

If you're not satisfied with doing this, though, there's another very fast algorithm you could try.  Essentially, you want to compute log<sub>2</sub> w/x.  You could start off by creating a table that lists all powers of two along with their logarithms.  For example, your table might look like

```
T[1] = 0
T[2] = 1
T[4] = 2
T[8] = 3
...
```

You could then compute w/x, then do a binary search to figure out where in which range the value lies.  The upper bound of this range is then the number of times the ball must bounce.  This means that if you have k different pairs to inspect, and if you know that the maximum ratio of w/x is U, creating this table takes O(log U) time and each query then takes time proportional to the log of the size of the table, which is O(log log U).  The overall runtime is then O(log U + k log log U), which is extremely good.  Given that you're dealing with at most one million problem instances and that U is one billion, k log log U is just under five million, and log U is about thirty.

Finally, if you're willing to do some perversely awful stuff with bitwise hackery, since you know for a fact that w/x fits into a 32-bit word, you can use **[this bitwise trickery with IEEE doubles](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogIEEE64Float)** to compute the logarithm in a very small number of machine operations.  This would probably be faster than the above two approaches, though I can't necessarily guarantee it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, I think I get this one... Thank you very much! :)

Comment: +1 Precompute. Or rather, compute as required and then store in dictionary.

Comment: what kind of numerical problems do you expect from taking the log?  really there is no excuse here not to do so - just check that the argument is greater than zero first.  there is absolutely no need to mess around with tabulating values.  just do the math.

Comment: @andrew cooke- I'm not sure if you need to worry at all.  What I'm concerned about would be some case where you take a log and get back a value like 2.000000001 instead of 2.0 and thus end up giving back the wrong answer (since the ceiling will hand back 3 instead of 2, you have the wrong number of bounces).  It's possible that this will never come up, but I would be very skeptical that using logarithms and floating-point numbers would work correctly in all cases without seeing either a proof or a sample program proving that you don't need to worry.

Comment: ok.  i deleted an earlier reply because it seemed too critical - this kind of thing seems excessive to me, but i guess it's just a difference of opinion.

Comment: @andrew cooke- I'm currently running a test to see if the numerical instability actually is a problem or not.  I've found that if you use `float`s to hold the values, you do indeed get the wrong answer at a few points.  Right now I'm trying to see if you always get the right answer with `double`s, but it's a pretty big space to search.  I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @andrew cooke- Yep, it looks like it breaks for `double`s as well on some numbers.  So I guess my concern was justified after all.

Comment: sorry, i think you misunderstood me.  i don't think the log is guaranteed to avoid rounding errors any more than any other floating point math.  i just thing it's excessive to reduce everything to integer maths unless there's a clear need for a "perfect" example (along the lines of putting a man on the moon for example).  floating point maths is used every day, and is good enough for almost all problems - a log is well enough behaved to avoid any "pathological" behaviour.  what you are doing seems to me more like "showboating" where a smart student goes overboard just to get approval.

Comment: @andrew cooke- Ah, I see what you're saying.  I agree with you - in most instances, you definitely can use floating-point math and you'll be just fine.  However, for this particular problem, since it seemed like it was a part of a programming contest (note the very rigorous definitions of the inputs and outputs), I thought that exact answers were necessary here, and so I went into detail about how to obtain an exact answer.  Also, the OP was very concerned about efficiency (note that the OP was worried about the naive doubling algorithm), so I went into detail about how to maximize efficiency.

Comment: yeah, you may be right.  that's why i changed my reply earlier to say it could be just a difference of opinion.  peace...

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula to calculate the number of bounces for each test case.

```
ceil( log(w/x) / log(2) )
```

This is pseudo-code, but it should be pretty simple to convert it to any language. Just replace log with a function that finds the logarithm of a number in some specific base and replace ceil with a function that rounds up a given decimal value to the next int above it (for example, ceil(2.3) = 3).

See http://www.purplemath.com/modules/solvexpo2.htm for why this works (in your case, you're trying to solve the equation x * 2 ^ n = w for an integer n, and you should start by dividing both sides by x).

**EDIT:**
Before using this method, you should check that w > x and return 1 if it isn't. (The ball always has to bounce at least once).

Also, it has been pointed out that inaccuracies in floating point values may cause this method to sometimes fail. You can work around this by checking if 2 ^ (n-1) >= w, where n is the result of the equation above, and if so returning (n - 1) instead of n.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly if you use IEEE floating-point values due to inaccuracies that can appear in the numbers.  See my above answer for details.